# email validation in jquery validate js resulting in ie 8 hanging

Tags: regex, jquery-plugins

The email validation given in jquery validate results in internet explorer 8 browser hanging when we add a long mail id like this

A@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXyz

return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+([.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+$/i.test(value);

what could be the possible changes made to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type = "email" name="email" />
```

This would work

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I need to work on HTML 4 tag only.. Anything we can do to the regex. I noticed the problem is due to the \. in the end which when removed solves the problem, yet we need it to be there..